# How to determine when the last time dhcp address was updated

Tags: linux

In Linux, How can I determine when the last time dhcp address was updated?

IP is set to Static mode however I would like to know what was the last IP DHCP allocate it when it was DHCP

Where can I find the logs?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the info you need on the DHCP client under:

```
 /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.<interface>.leases
```